# Update postgresql Database Column in Django

Tags: python, arrays, django, postgresql

I'm trying to save data to a 2D array within a PostgreSql database, the data is stored as following:

```
"[('User 1', 'User 2', 'User3', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '')]"
```

This represents a single array within a single column of the database, this data is accessed via the following Python Code, which requests the correct row in the database and then the relevant column

```
q = DBReports.objects.all().filter(name__contains = username)  
q = q.values_list(columnName)
```

In order to iterate through the data retrieved, it is then placed into a list

```
 users_list = ast.literal_eval(q[0][0])
```

The correct array within the column is then selected using the following code:

```
 for list in users_list:
                if user in list[2]:
                    listToUse = list
```

The issue i'm running into is that now with the retrieved data, I need to change it and resave to the database (listToUse is changed with the blanks filled in), such that the array may now for example represent

```
"[('User 1', 'User 2', 'User3', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', '11', '12', '13', '14', '15', '16', '17', '19')]"
```

How would i go about updating the data that was stored in the array, or replacing the array with the new created list of the same structure, I'm using django's database abstraction to handle all the data

Comment: A general rule of thumb when using arrays in databases is that if you need to search within that array, don't use arrays.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was solved by taking all information from the returned queryset, storing this in variables/list, updating those variables with the required information, and then saving this to the database.

Requesting information:

```
q = DBReports.objects.all().filter(name__contains = assessor)  
qValues = q.values_list(columnName)

if len(qValues) > 0:
            users_list = ast.literal_eval(qValues[0][0])

            usernameToAppend = q[0].username
            nameToAppend = q[0].name
            mn= users_list[0][1]
            EOS= q[0].EOS
            RW= q[0].RW
            temp = (assessor, mn, assessee, '','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','')
            users_list.append(temp)
            recordToAppend = DBReports(username = usernameToAppend,name = nameToAppend, RW = users_list, EOS = evaluationsOfSelf, RW = RW)
```